# Converting string column to timestamp in BigQuery?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, google-bigquery, schema

I am trying to convert a column in a BQ table to timestamp. I have two string columns, one for utc_hour (string 0-23) and utc_day (string yyyymmdd) imported from a public data source. I merged the two columns to produce a string column, utc_timestamp, with strings like this - "20171208 500" .

I need to convert that string into timestamp, and when I use

```
TIMESTAMP(utc_timestamp)
```

I get the error message

```
Invalid timestamp: '20171208 500'
```

I tried using dataprep, which also could not convert that string to a timestamp.

How can I convert this format to a timestamp?

Comment: What does the `500` represent?

Comment: You are probably after STR_TO_DATE function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: The question title says, "In BigQuery", so `STR_TO_DATE` does not apply (you would use `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` in BigQuery).

Comment: Possible. For me it is not clear from the question at what stage the conversion is needed (BigQuery mentioned along with MySQL).

Comment: the 500 represents the fifth hour, or 5am.  STR_TO_DATE does not apply and PARSE_TIMESTAMP also returns "Failed to parse input string '20171208 500' "

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to parse with **%Y%m%d%k%M** format.

```
PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m%d%k%M", utc_timestamp)
```

Comment: interesting, this makes sense intuitively, and now I am getting "Failed to parse input string "20170115 0", but if I manually put in '20171208 500' instead of utc_timestamp, the query runs.

Trying to figure out what it is about the 0 that trips this up?

Comment: I think I got it, by including "%M" the query also parses minutes, so 500 will be 5:00. If I change all 0's to 000, the query runs. Alternatively, I can delete the %M, and divide the timestamp column by 100, and everything runs smoothly as well.

Comment: Yes, %M denotes The minute as a decimal number (00-59).

Comment: The format elements table: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time

Answer (score 1):

This question is already answered but in case someone else visits here with his/her own unique timestamp format (in which case the accepted answer might not work), you need to follow the notations on this [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#supported_format_elements_for_timestamp)

For eg, in my case values were like this `2020-05-11-00:00:00`. So, I went to the above-mentioned page and found that the format string that I needed would be something like `%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S`.

I will put the description for the ones that I used in my format string:

```
%d  The day of the month as a decimal number (01-31).
%H  The hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number (00-23).
%M  The minute as a decimal number (00-59).
%m  The month as a decimal number (01-12).
%S  The second as a decimal number (00-60).
%Y  The year with century as a decimal number.
```

The `:`s and the `-`s are quite self-explanatory.